# Actual Toplevel in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In python there is a tk.messagebox.showinfo(), that shows message. I am unable to access main window, while this messagebox is shown.

```
import tkinter as tk
win_a=tk.Tk()
tk.messagebox.showinfo()
win_a.focus_set()
```

And if i try, messagebox will make a 'critical sound' and flash itself.
How do i make Toplevel() window behave like that? .grab_set() don't make any sound or flashes.

```
import tkinter as tk
win_a=tk.Tk()
win_b=tk.Toplevel(a)
# Now i want to make win_a disabled, and flash win_b if touched
# win_b code here
win_b.destroy()
win_a.focus_set()
```

Comment: Please provide a sample code to work upon.

Comment: Hello LazyBum Q! In asking question on stackoverflow, it's a good idea to put some sample code that you have worked on so that we can also test it out on our side. It's a good idea to do that cause some people might downvote your question causing you not to be able to ask questions anymore in the future. Thank you!

Comment: You need to disable main window using `attributes("-disabled", 1)`.  Make sure you enable back the main window after closing the toplevel.

Comment: win_a.attributes("-disabled", 1) do not flash Toplevel window.

Comment: Make the toplevel a transient window of main window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668)'s suggestions, I made this code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
top = Toplevel()
# disabling main window
root.attributes('-disabled',1)
# forcing Toplevel to flash when main window is touched
top.transient(root)
# some Toplevel window code goes here..

# Enabling main window
root.attributes('-disabled',0)
```